# Would a technology tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel like the following question is missing a tag:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2015/8

that would highlight that this question is about [technology](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) or physical device.

Would you think creating tag like [technology](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) will help? Or it would be too broad, or do you have any better suggestion? Or it is fine as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the question you linked is suitably tagged, but I don't think a `technology` tag will help better categorize content.

"Technology" is one of those *broad* terms that can be applied to many many things. I think  a `technology` tag would be applied inconsistently at best, and it will *likely* attract a lot of unrelated questions without adding any clarity to what they are about.